# Unable to execute script file with +x permission, even with sudo

Tags: linux, permissions

I am unable to run scripts from a mounted partition. I have created a basic "Hello World" script that will execute from my home directory fine, but when I move it to the mounted partition, I am unable to execute the file.

```
$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user    31 Mar  4 21:33 test.sh
$ ./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
$ sudo ./test.sh
[sudo] password for user:
sudo: unable to execute ./test.sh: Permission denied
$ cd ..
$ ls -l
drwxrwxrwx  6 user root  4096 Mar  4 21:34 sda5
```

I have no idea what to do.

ETA: I am able to use "bash test.sh" to execute the file, just not ./test.sh. I am able to do ./test.sh in the home directory.

Comment: What filesystem is the mounted partition?

Comment: Is the partition mounted with noexec flag?

Comment: HevyLight: File system is ext4

Comment: hex2mgl: I'm not sure, how do I check?

Comment: type `mount` in your terminal. Search the output for the partition where test.sh is located. Mounting flags are at the end of the line in  `()` brackets. Do you see the `noexec` there? (likely)

Comment: /dev/sda5 on /media/sda5 type ext4 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)

It looks like you're right

Comment: There you have the problem :) how get the partition mounted? at boot? (fstab) or have you mounted the partition manually?

Comment: I was using pysdm because I didn't feel like finding the UUID. I have the partition mount on boot. To actually fix the issue, I added `exec` to the boot options for the partition.

Answer (score 30):

The file system was mounted with noexec which prevented executing files.

Comment: I'm using the 'Disks' tool on Ubuntu (via the GUI) and was able to simply add the `exec` option. That seems to of prevented the `noexec` which is automatically added when the `user` option is used. And now I can run the file as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If the file in the mount position is not own by the same user in the home directory, then can also give possible reasons for the file to be unable to be executed using;

```
     ./
```

this is because when you do ./, it means you are executing in your pwd, but when you pass an interpreter 'bash' the file is executed without executable permission,

so verify the owner of the file in the mount position, if it's own by the root, then you cannot use ./ to execute the file, except you change the user