# Not able to install anaconda on linux, getting error path_to_dir/conda.exe : Permisison denied

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, installation, anaconda

I'm trying to install anaconda on my Ubuntu 20.04. It is giving me error

> [/home_dir/anaconda3] >>> /mount_path of different_ssd/anaconda3
> PREFIX=/mount_path of different_ssd/anaconda3 Unpacking payload ...
> Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 407:
> /mount_path of different_ssd/anaconda3/conda.exe: Permission denied
> Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 409:
> /mount_path of different_ssd/anaconda3/conda.exe: Permission denied

I'm trying to install it on a different SSD. The permissions for the installation folder is

> drwxrwxr-x 2 user user  4096 Jul 16 14:06 anaconda3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ssd was mounted with options `auto,exec,rw,user`. After removing `user`, I was able to install the miniconda3. The comment in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214890/unable-to-execute-script-file-with-x-permission-even-with-sudo) gave me the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the permission of that specific directory using

```
sudo chmod -R a+w direcotry/
```

This will give write permissions to all the users.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: have you used `sudo` before changing the mode, you can use `su -u` and try installing the package, and also check if the mount directory is mounted as `exec` or `noexec`

Comment: The disk is mounted with rw,exec,user options. The file system is ext4.